# Minishop2 вывести товар в модальном окне MODx Revo

Tags: javascript, html, css, modx

```
[msGallery] The resource with id = 9 is not instance of msProduct.
```

Как передать id в modx revo minishop2

```
<div class="action-view">
            <button type="button" class="btn" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Просмотр</button>
</div>
<div id="quickview-wrapper">
   [[! WayRowTpl]] × [[! MsGallery]]
      <div class="product-info">
          <h1>[[*pagetitle]]</h1>
          <div class="price-box">
            <p class="price"><span class="special-price"><span class="amount"><b> [[+price]] [[%ms2_frontend_currency]]</b></span></span></p>
          </div>
          <p class="availability in-stock">Наличие: 
            [[*avaible:eq=`1`:then=`<span>В наличии</span>`]]
            [[*avaible:eq=`2`:then=`<span>Под заказ</span>`]]
            [[*avaible:eq=`0`:then=`<span>Нет в наличии</span>`]]
          </p>
          <a href="product-details.html" class="see-all">Перейти к товару</a>
          <div class="quick-add-to-cart">
            <form method="post" class="cart">
              <div class="add-to-box add-to-box2">
                <div class="add-to-cart">
                  <div class="input-content">
                    <label for="qty">Количество:</label>
                    <input type="button" class="qty-decrease" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) &amp;&amp; qty &gt; 0 ) qty_el.value--;return false;" value="-">
                    <!--<input type="text" class="input-text qty" title="Qty" value="1" maxlength="12" id="qty" name="qty">-->
                    <input type="number" name="count" id="product_price" maxlength="12" class="input-text qty" value="1"/>
                    <input type="button" class="qty-increase" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) qty_el.value++;return false;" value="+">
                  </div>
                  [[*avaible:neq=`0`:then=`
                  <button type="submit" class="btn" name="ms2_action" value="cart/add"><span>Добавить в корзину</span></button>`]]
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="quick-desc">
            [[*description]]
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Повтор вопроса не приветсвуется - попробуйте перефразировать вопрос или добавить новые детали, которые вы выяснили по данному вопросу. Как вариант - у вас наверняка есть источник данных  - дайте нам посмотреть какие данные будут переданы сюада ( только не надо все - только в районе id 7 - 11 ). В остальном коментарий к копии данного вопроса верно описывает первое что на ум приходит - проверьте что тип данных у передаваемых объектов подходит msProduct. Возможно под индексом 9 это или null или же иные данные. А возможно просто выход за пределы перечисления.

Answer (score 1):

У тебя большие проблемы с указанием каких-либо деталей того что ты хочешь, но то, что ты написал в названии обычно делается в модикс вот так:

Первое - выводишь ссылку на твой товар при щелчке по которой должно открываться модальное окно. Что-то вроде этого:

```
<a href="[[~адишниктовара]]" class="show_me_all_things">названиетовара</a>
```

Прежде чем идти дальше надо подготовить шаблон самого товара - завернуть контент который ты хочешь вывести в див с адищником к которому впоследствии будем цепляться:

```
<div id="our_modal_content">
    ...тут весь твой контент товара который нужно выводить в модальном окне...
</div>
```

Затем на класс ссылки навешиваем через javascript обработчик события клика и делаем открытие модального окна - например через [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)(css и js файлы колорбокса подключи предварительно к странице):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".show_me_all_things").colorbox({
            href: function() {
                return $(this).attr('href')+' #our_modal_content';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```